# How to search most relative items using title and tags

Tags: mysql, search, tags

I have the web which have main content on the left hand side and the relative item titles on the right strip like in Youtube.

What I want is to query the most relative items to show on the right strip like in Youtube.com.

More info:
On the page showing any item, there are item title, pix, very short description, and tags(limited to 5).

In database I record number of views, number of vote on page, and number of comments.
My very problem is my web is in Thai that all words in item title and description are written by mean of no spacing between words, this make it difficult to find or retrieve keywords form title and description.

What I do now is just to query item which have similar tag or tags and sorted by number of view. It work very well for different items that are not closed in story. I observed that it appear almost the same results for items that have the same tag(even if 1 tag). I think it should show different result on any item like in youtube.com .

Techical info:
I have main tables: `entry, entry_tag, tag.`

Table entry stores `entry_id, title,number of view, number of vote, number of comment, etc.`
Table entry_tag stores `entry_id, tag_id`

Table tag stores `tag_id and tag`

My current code is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM entry AS t1
INNER JOIN entry_tag AS t2 ON t1.entry_id=t2.entry_id
INNER JOIN tag AS t3 ON t2.tag_id=t3.tag_id
INNER JOIN tag AS t4 ON t3.tag=t4.tag
INNER JOIN entry_tag  AS t5 ON t4.tag_id=t5.tag_id 
WHERE t5.entry_id={$entry_id} AND t1.entry_id!={$entry_id}
ORDER BY view  DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Any idea or suggestion to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have extra joins in your query that make no sense to me. I would do the query like this...

```
select distinct entry.* 
from entry
join entry_tag on (entry.entry_id = entry_tag.entry_id)
join tag on (entry_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id)
where tag.tag_id in (<comma separated list of tag id's>)
order by entry.number_of_views desc
limit 20
```

I'd pass in the list of tag_id based on the tags on the current article you are displaying. This way you will get a list of all entries that have the same tag ordered by those which have been viewed the most first. You may also want to order by tag popularity and number of similar tags as well in order to get the trendy topics to the top of the list with the most tags in common.

Comment: The extra join in my code is from idea that i want to query with a single input as entry_id and to avoid additional query to get tag_id, so that code gives me all distinct entry_id and all fields in the same row. Your code is also a good idea especially to order by tag populartity and similar tag. Do you have the idea to do this in a single query? Thanks.